Spacing is incorrect for datagrip (postgresql) + mac
Take this code:
CREATE TABLE list_tag(
    list_id VARCHAR(36),
    name VARCHAR(25)
);

If I duplicate this line in Datagrip I get this:
CREATE TABLE list_tag(
                           list_id VARCHAR(36),
                           name VARCHAR(25)
  );

Suddenly 4 spaces turn into 27. Same issue occurs if i have an empty CREATE TABLE and try pasting something in there. I checked my spacing options for sql and postgres, they're just 4 spaces.
Curiously, newlining the opening brace, done like this does work
CREATE TABLE user_list
(
    list_id VARCHAR(36),
    username VARCHAR(25)
);

However, that's just not my personal preference, so I don't know if there's a solution to this or if it's just forced into datagrip.

To investigate this behavior, please report your issue here
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE
